# Update JLabel from another class doesn't work Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Here I have two classes there are **PanelEdit** and **Snapshot** which the classes *extends* jPanel

there is a **jLabel** on class **PanelEdit**. I want to update the JLabel on class PanelEdit from Snapshot class

my program flow : user have to open PanelEdit before open Snapshot, so after hit a button from Snapshot class, then would be update jLabel on PanelEdit.

> open PanelEdit -> Open Snapshot -> user hit button on Snapshot -> update jLabel on PanelEdit

My attempts are :

1. create method setter on PanelEdit :

```
public void setLabel(String label){
    jLabel1.setText(label);
}
```

then on Snapshot hit the setter method :

```
 PanelEdit pe = new PanelEdit();
 pe.setLabel("test");
```

but my `jLabel` on `PanelEdit` doesn't update

2. set public `jLabel` on `PanelEdit`, so Snapshot could access it directly

```
PanelEdit pe = new PanelEdit();
pe.jLabel1.setText("test");
```

and still doesn't update,

anyone can help me out ?

Comment: You cannot just create a new PanelEdit and set the text on that one. You have to set the text on the displayed PanelEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example.

```
PanelEdit a = new PanelEdit();
PanelEdit b = new PanelEdit();

a.setLabel("what");
b.setLabel("else");
```

In this example, a.jLabel1 will have the text "what". b.jLabel1 will have the text "else".

You need a reference to the PanelEdit you created when you built your gui.